# Can OVERLAPBDYDISJOINT or ON ever occur between two polygons?

Tags: oracle-dbms, sdo-geometry

Oracle uses a series of specific [spatial relationships](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/spatial-relationships-and-filtering.htm#SPATL460) to indicate the how different shapes interact with each other.

Two of the relationships it describes are somewhat odd:

> OVERLAPBDYDISJOINT: The interior of one object intersects the boundary and interior of the other object, but the two boundaries do not intersect. This relationship occurs, for example, when a line originates outside a polygon and ends inside that polygon.

and

> ON: The interior and boundary of one object is on the boundary of the other object. This relationship occurs, for example, when a line is on the boundary of a polygon.

Am I correct that these can *never* happen with two shapes that are the same inherent dimensionality? That is, a polygon can never have this relationship with another polygon, and a line can never have this relationship with another line. It can only happen if I have a point and a polygon, a line and a polygon, or a point and a line. Or have I misunderstood?